# What is the filling time of this liquid storage tank?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

[image: Sodium pumping problem.]

A spherical storage tank ($R=3\:\mathrm{m}$, heated just enough to keep the sodium liquid) has to be filled from the lowest point with liquid sodium (at just above its melting point). A pump, very close to the tank, delivers a constant $2.5\:\mathrm{bar}$ of pressure through a smooth pipe of $7.5\:\mathrm{cm}$ internal diameter.

For safety reasons an argon blanket is maintained above the sodium at $1.2\:\mathrm{bar}$ by the argon venting valve.

Ignoring all friction, drag or inertia, **calculate the estimated filling time**.

Using Bernoulli's Equation it is possible to determine that the volumetric flow $Q_V(z)$ into the tank varies according to:

$$Q_V(z)=\frac{1}{\alpha} \sqrt{2\Big(\frac{\Delta p}{\rho}-gz\Big)}$$

Where $\Delta p = 1.3\:\mathrm{bar}$ and $z$ the height of the liquid level measured from the bottom of the tank. $\alpha$ depends on the cross-sections of feed line and tank.

If the full expression of $Q_V(z)$ was known then we can say (with $V$ tank volume):

$$dV=A_zdz=Q_V(z)dt$$,

With $A_z$ the tank's cross-section at $z$.

Integration between $t=0, z=0$ and $t_f, z=2R$ would then yield filling time $t_f$. But the dependence of both $\alpha$ and $A_z$ on $z$ makes the integration really difficult.

Is it possible to solve it this way or is there perhaps a different way to approach the problem?

Comment: Do we know the velocity of the flow in the pipe? Without a velocity (in a cross section of pipe or container), the number of unknowns will be greater than the number of equations.

Comment: The velocity in the pipe is determined using Bernoulli. The real problem is the dependence of $\alpha$ and $A_z$ on $z$ because the tank is spherical. If the tank as an upright cylinder this would be 'easy'.

Comment: We have three equations, but four unknowns. Equations are: $\large{\frac{P_1}{\rho g}}+\large{\frac{V_1^2}{2g}}=\large{\frac{P_2}{\rho g}}+\large{\frac{V_2^2}{2g}}+z$ ; $A_1V_1=A_2V_2$ and $A_2=\pi \left(2Rz-z^2\right)$. Unknowns are: $V_1$, $V_2$, $A_2$ and $z$.

Comment: May you write whole of your solution?

Comment: @lucas: $A_2$ isn't unknown: it's a function of $z$. Solution for a cylindrical tank:  http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65505&page=2#pid440937

Comment: You are right. I had forgotten two equations: $Q=AV$

Comment: The problem is that $A_2(z)$ is fairly complicated. That makes the integration hard. That's why I was wondering about a different approach altogether?

Comment: I have a problem with your solution for both questions (current question and that question you linked). Since $v_0$ and $A_0$ are constant, hence $Q=v_0A_0$ must be constant. But in both of your solutions $Q$ is a function of $z$ and varies with that. I couldn’t find out where is wrong but it seems there is a mistake. May you clarify for me?

Comment: I think $P_1$ (pressure just after pump) isn't constant. The problem says that pump delivers a constant $2.5\:\mathrm{bar}$ of pressure, it doesn't say that the pressure after pump is $2.5\:\mathrm{bar}$. So, I think $\Delta P$ isn't constant.

Comment: You're misunderstanding Bernoulli. $p_0$ is constant because *I specify so*. $v_0$  isn't constant because kinetic energy is being converted to potential energy. Trust me, for a cylinder the only error that is made here is to neglect inertia: if $v_0$ decreases with $z$, then there's deceleration. But I explicitly stated to neglect that.

Comment: $v_0$ is constant because liquids are incompressible. $v_0$ is the velocity of  flow inside the pipe.

Comment: Imagine the problem in reverse. No pump and the tank is emptying by gravity, basically Torricelli for an emptying tank. Would $v_0$ be constant, despite the fluid being incompressible? Of course not! It's the same here. You're *over-thinking* this, Lucas.

Comment: Why not ask a similar question and see what you get?

Comment: Nevermind sir. I just wanted to help. Forgive me if I bothered you.